# Identify book where mother is in shampoo commercials

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to find a book I once read, but I do not know the title. The only thing that I remember is that the main character is a boy in high school whose parents are divorced. He lives with his father and does not get to see his mother who is a model in shampoo commercials. At the end of the book he meet his mom.

I know that this book exists because my friend has also read it, but neither of us remember the name.

Comment: Welcome to our site! To help us track it down, can you give any additional details? For example, how long ago did you read it? What country was it published in? What language was it in (or could it have been a translation)? Do you remember any details that might indicate the setting for the story (e.g. city vs rural, suburban house or inner-city apartment, etc)? PS if you can, it's best to [edit] your question rather than replying to my comment. :-)